# Gridview not refreshing images after taking picture from camera

Tags: android, gridview

I am new to android development and I am facing an issue when I capture an image from camera, it doesn't show up in the gridview immediately, if I refresh the activity or reload it than it is appearing in the gridview.
I have searched a lot and implemented various solutions but no one worked for me, please advice, following is my code.

My xml file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/userHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           layout="@layout/header_user" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/userTable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/historyDateRow">
        <TextView  android:text="@string/historyDateCaption" style="@style/captionStyle" />
        <TextView  android:id="@+id/viwHistoryDate" style="@style/captionStyle" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/historyUpdateDateRow">
        <TextView  android:text="@string/historyUpdateDateCaption" style="@style/captionStyle" />
        <TextView  android:id="@+id/viwHistoryUpdateDate" style="@style/captionStyle" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
        <TextView  android:text="@string/historyCaption"  style="@style/captionStyle" />
        <TextView  android:text=""  style="@style/captionStyle" />
    </TableRow>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtHistory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/save"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Capture"/>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my java file I have code like:

```
    String userId=null;
    String historyId = null;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
    File root = null;
    final String filesPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyProj" + File.separator+ "Images" + File.separator;
    private  List<String> listOfImagesPath;
    Boolean needsRefresh = false;
    GridView gridview = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.casehistory);
        GlobalVariables gv = ((GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext());

        userId=gv.getsUserId();
        historyId=getIntent().getStringExtra(ListHistory.ID_History);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

        String targetPath = "";

        if(historyId == null)
        {
            targetPath = filesPath + userId + File.separator;
            root = new File(filesPath + userId + File.separator);
        }
        else
        {
            targetPath = filesPath + userId + File.separator + historyId + File.separator;
            root = new File(filesPath + userId + File.separator + historyId + File.separator);
            gv.setsHistoryId(historyId);
        }

        root.mkdirs();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

        if(files!=null)
        {
            for (File file : files){
             myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } 
        }
        Button btCapture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        btCapture.setOnClickListener(onCapture);
    }
```

than I have onCapture as:

```
private View.OnClickListener onCapture=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        openImageIntent();
    }
};
```

than my openImageIntent is as:

```
private void openImageIntent() {
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.

    final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 212);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //CommonHelper.ShowErrorMessage("Result Code: " + String.valueOf(resultCode), CaseHistory.this);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        //CommonHelper.ShowErrorMessage("Request Code: " + String.valueOf(requestCode), CaseHistory.this);
        if(requestCode == 212)
        {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if(data == null)
            {
                isCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if(action == null)
                {
                    isCamera = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if(isCamera)
            {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
            }

            myImageAdapter.add(selectedImageUri.toString());
            //GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            //gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
            myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            gridview.invalidateViews();
            gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
            needsRefresh = true;
            //CommonHelper.ShowErrorMessage("Image URI: " + selectedImageUri.toString(), CaseHistory.this);

            //CommonHelper.ShowErrorMessage("Extra Data URI: " + data.getExtras().get("data"), CaseHistory.this);
        }
    }
}
```

and in end my Image adapter is as:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c; 
    }

    void add(String path){
         itemList.add(path); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
         if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
             imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
         } else {
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
         }

         Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

         imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
         return imageView;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        //  Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

        return bm;   
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
            }   
        }

        return inSampleSize;    
    }
 }
```

I have been struggling hard with it for last few days and have been trying different solutions from web but all in vain.
Can any body please help me in it?

***Humble Request***  This is my first android project as well as Java project, so if anyone have time and want to feed back on the way I am coding is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems ok to me except`selectedImageUri.toString()` this. 
Just replace `selectedImageUri.toString()` with `selectedImageUri.getPath()` and you should be good.

When you call toString() on any object what it will try do is give you information about that object as a whole. In your case when you are calling toString() on URI, it will not give you exact path to that file instead it will give something like `"file:///storage/emulated/0/MyProj/Images/111/222/img_1388856542838.jpg"` this.And since it's not an absolute filepath that's why decodeFile is not working in your adapter. On the other hand  when you restart your activity you are dealing with absolute filepath with `getAbsolutePath()` and that is why after restarting it is working. So to get the path from URI object you have to call getPath().

Answer (score 1):

I have found some useLess code there, Just do either, That may be a problem

`selectedImageUri.toString()` will not give you the path of the image you want it is retrieved using `selectedImageUri.getPath()`

```
myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //  This will try to load your new Image

gridview.invalidateViews(); // then you are refreshing views and setting the adapter again below

gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
```

use just

```
myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but the other answer was posted before you so I have marked that as answer.